# Create bash with xinetd

Tags: bash

I'm making an intentionally vulnerable Ubuntu server for an information security class. I'm trying to create a bash shell that is accessible without authentication, a user should just be able to connect with netcat and get a full shell. This is done in the metasploitable2 vm on port 1524.

Does anyone know the best way to set this up?

I know that metasploitable is using the xinetd service, but I can't find the necessary configuration in the xinetd.conf or the xinetd.d/ directory.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

The ingreslock port (tcp/1524 is being controlled by an entry in /etc/inetd.conf).

Essentially an interactive bash shell is being provided to the listening port; the seventh field of the inetd.conf entry shows this.

You can achieve similar results by creating a similar entry in inetd.conf or by creating your own service for xinetd to listen for.